# Can't load images from bundle into storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bundle

I've been working on a library that will be used across multiple applications. This library also includes resources like a storyboard and many images. I recently made this library into a .framework using the iOS Framework tutorial found on Github.

When I was first working on this library, it was in the form of an app. When I got most of the coding done, I made it into a framework. However, this is where my problem began.

I am able to present the storyboard (`Engine.bundle/Platform.storyboardc`), and the first screen shows which has a background image which loads. However, once I get to all of the other screens in this storyboard, the images on those screens don't load. What's weird is that the first screen image loads through the storyboard without having to set it in the code. All the other images from the storyboard don't load, yet they are all contained in the same bundle as the first image.

One of the next screen contains credit card images, which do not load. And on the screen after that, more credit card images don't load. However, once I set the images through the .m file, they load from the bundle and show on the screen. Yet when I use this same code on every other screen that doesn't show their respective images, the code doesn't work. Here's the code I'm using to load their respective images:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Engine" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"front" ofType: @"png"];

backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Whenever the screens that don't have images loaded are presented, the following is logged to the console:

```
Could not load the "visa.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.app"
Could not load the "mastercard.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.app"
... and so on and so forth for each image.
```

And it even shows on the second credit card image screen... the screen where the images actually load. Yet, it doesn't show on the very first screen presented where the image loads.

My bundle is structured like so:

```
Engine.bundle/
    Platform.storyboardc
    front.png
    visa.png
    amex.png
    ... so on and so forth.
```

My question is why don't the images load? And why do some load? front.png loads, and on only one screen do the credit card images show. Yet when I use the same code to load the images on to other screens, the code doesn't work.

Sorry if this post is long... it's a lot of detail. I've just been really trying to figure this out. If I didn't explain something right, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: does your Engine.bundle have the identifier "`com.example.app`"?  I suspect not.  So where is "`com.example.app`" coming from?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann "com.example.app" is coming from the testing app that I built to incorporate my custom framework and bundle.

Comment: Does your Engine.bundle have it's own identifier and/or info.plist file?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes, it has an Info.plist with "Bundle identifier" set to "com.example.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it sounds like you need to set the bundle identifier for your Engine bundle.

Use something like "com.IAmSoAwesome.engine"

Then, instead of using:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Engine" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

You can use:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier: @"com.IAmSoAwesome.engine"];
```

Comment: The console is still logging that it can't find the visa.png etc.

Comment: even after you clean and rebuild the app and/or remove the app from the simulator and reinstall it?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Platform' in bundle NSBundle </Users/Alec/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/9BB794DF-14B0-4C0F-81D0-C703BF7D884F/Example.app> (loaded)'

Comment: OK so I have no clue what happened, but somehow everything works fine. My problem was solved mysteriously. Thanks for your help with the bundle identifier line, that helped in certain places. Thanks Michael.